# Aggregate function in R using two columns simultaneously

Tags: r, aggregate, summarization

Data:-

```
df=data.frame(Name=c("John","John","Stacy","Stacy","Kat","Kat"),Year=c(2016,2015,2014,2016,2006,2006),Balance=c(100,150,65,75,150,10))

   Name Year Balance
1  John 2016     100
2  John 2015     150
3 Stacy 2014      65
4 Stacy 2016      75
5   Kat 2006     150
6   Kat 2006      10
```

Code:-

```
aggregate(cbind(Year,Balance)~Name,data=df,FUN=max )
```

Output:-

```
   Name Year Balance
1  John 2016     150
2   Kat 2006     150
3 Stacy 2016      75
```

I want to aggregate/summarize the above data frame using two columns which are Year and Balance. I used the base function **aggregate** to do this. I need the maximum balance of the latest year/ most recent year . The first row in the output , John has the latest year (2016) but the balance of (2015) , which is not what I need, it should output 100 and not 150. where am I going wrong in this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somewhat ironically, `aggregate` is a poor tool for aggregating. You could make it work, but I'd instead do:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[order(-Year, -Balance), .SD[1], by = Name]
#    Name Year Balance
#1:  John 2016     100
#2: Stacy 2016      75
#3:   Kat 2006     150
```

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest to use the library dplyr:

```
data.frame(Name=c("John","John","Stacy","Stacy","Kat","Kat"),
           Year=c(2016,2015,2014,2016,2006,2006),
           Balance=c(100,150,65,75,150,10)) %>% #create the dataframe
    tbl_df() %>% #convert it to dplyr format
    group_by(Name, Year) %>% #group it by Name and Year
    summarise(maxBalance=max(Balance)) %>% # calculate the maximum for each group
    group_by(Name) %>% # group the resulted dataframe by Name
    top_n(1,maxBalance) # return only the first record of each group
```

Comment: Nice one, but I would go with the carbon copy of @eddi's answer: `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% arrange(desc(Year),desc(Balance)) %>% filter(1)`

Comment: @MaratTalipov nice answer!

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution without the data.table package.

first sort the data frame,

```
df <- df[order(-df$Year, -df$Balance),]
```

then select the first one in each group with the same name

```
df[!duplicated[df$Name],]
```